# Relation between functors under an equivalence

Tags: category-theory, functors

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be three categories and $G\colon A\to C$ and $H\colon B\to C$ two functors. Assume that $F\colon A\to B$ and $E\colon B\to A$ form an equivalence between $A$ and $B$.

Suppose that

$$
H \circ F = G \qquad \text{and} \qquad G \circ E = H 
$$

(which should be equivalent to say that the triangle formed by $A$, $B$, and $C$ as objects and $F$, $E$, $G$, and $H$ as morphism commutes, since $F$ is an equivalence).

Is there a property, a definition, or a concept in general that describes such a relation between $H$ and $G$ under the equivalence $F$?

Comment: What is $F^{-1}$ here? The fact that $F$ is an equivalence does not guarantee the existence of an inverse.

Comment: $F^{-1}$ is the pseudo-inverse (that's how it is called on the book I'm studying) of $F$ that yields the equivalence. I edit the question to make this point clear (and I change $F^{-1}$ to $E$).

Comment: Are you sure you want to require _equalities_ of functors $H\circ F = G$ and $G\circ E =H$ and not natural isomorphisms?